# bind data from different requests in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

On my page I'm rendering panel with 6 categories. The categories come from api call:

```
var getCategories = function (customUrl) {

    $http.get(customUrl).then(function success(response) {
        $scope.categories = response.data;
        // console.log($scope.categories);
        // ****
    },
    function error(response) {
        console.log("It has happened error in categories response", response)
    });
};
```

inside of this request I have angular.forEach loop, where I'm sending api request for each category separately

```
angular.forEach($scope.categories, function (category) {

    var queryString = '?categoryId=',
        url = urlData + queryString;

    var getArrayLength = function(url){
        $http.get(url)
            .then(function success(response) {
                $scope.getLength = response.data;
                console.log($scope.getLength)

            }, function error(response) {
                console.log("error in getting length", response)
            });
    };

    getArrayLength(url + category.id);

    category.selected = $scope.selectedAllCat;
});
```

for now everything looks good, console log for `$scope.getLength` returns 6 different arrays `$scope.getLength.length` returns length for those arrays

Now I'm rendering table on my page like

```
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table">
   <tr>
       <td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" 
           ng-model="selectedAllCat"
           ng-click="selectAllCat()">&nbsp;</td>
       <td class="col-md-9">All</td>
       <td class="col-md-2">
           {{ initialDataLength.length }}
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy : 'id' ">
       <td class="col-md-1">
          <input type="checkbox"
                 ng-model="category.selected"
                 ng-click="updateFilter(category.id)">&nbsp;
       </td>
       <td class="col-md-9">{{ category.name }}</td>
       <td class="col-md-2">
                            {{ getLength.length }}
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That's my trouble point. How could I bind array's length with category name? Now it's showing only same length across each category name. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an object mapping category ids with length, and load the values after each request.

```
$scope.categoryLenghts = {};
angular.forEach($scope.categories, function (category) {

    var queryString = '?categoryId=',
        url = urlData + queryString;

    var getArrayLength = function(url){
       $http.get(url)
           .then(function success(response) {
               $scope.getLength = response.data;
               $scope.categoryLengths[category.id] = response.data // Save category length
               console.log($scope.getLength)

            }, function error(response) {
                console.log("error in getting length", response)
            });
    };
    getArrayLength(url + category.id);

    category.selected = $scope.selectedAllCat;
});
```

Then render it like this:

```
<td class="col-md-9">{{ category.name }}</td>
<td class="col-md-2">{{ categoryLengths[category.id] }}</td>
```

Comment: thank you Damian!! works as I expected, just need some modification in your post like `<td class="col-md-2">{{ categoryLengths[category.id].length }}</td>`

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `length` property to your individual category object as well.

```
angular.forEach($scope.categories, function (category) {
    var queryString = '?categoryId=',
    url = urlData + queryString;

    var getArrayLength = function(url){
    $http.get(url)
        .then(function success(response) {
            category.categoryLength = response.data.length;
            //console.log($scope.getLength)

        }, function error(response) {
            console.log("error in getting length", response)
        });
};
getArrayLength(url + category.id);
category.selected = $scope.selectedAllCat;
});
```

And

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy : 'id' ">
   <td class="col-md-1">
      <input type="checkbox"
             ng-model="category.selected"
             ng-click="updateFilter(category.id)">&nbsp;
   </td>
   <td class="col-md-9">{{ category.name }}</td>
   <td class="col-md-2">{{ category.categoryLength }} </td>
</tr>
```